# General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I installed new system (Ubuntu 20.04), I installed LAMP and cloned Laravel project. I created database blog and I wanted to migrate but I have this error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer
>   ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist (SQL: select * from
>   information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_name =
>   migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Change username to root, and as i expect your root does not have a password, so just set empty password.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the error "The user specified as 'user@localhost' does not exist," you have to follow this option:

Create the User: If the user 'user@localhost' does not exist in your database, you can create it. You can use the appropriate SQL command to create a new user with the necessary privileges. For example:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_database.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Replace 'user' with the desired username and 'password' with a secure password. Also, make sure to adjust 'your_database' to the actual name of your database.

You can check the users list with this sql query:

```
SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running MySQL 8?

`mysql.infoschema` is an account that [comes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reserved-users.html) with MySQL. If your system does not have one, make sure you have run [mysql_upgrade](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html).

Comment: Yes, I have Mysql 8

Answer (score 0):

`'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost'` does not exist. Either it never existed, or it was existed and removed/altered. Log in with root and run the following query:

```
SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user;
```

see what lines you find for `mysql.infoschema` and what hosts are there. It's possible that you are just not specifying the host properly, or the user was renamed, whatever. You might need to (re)create this user.